# Programatically refreshing the model data in ASP.Net MVC with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I may be missing something here, but I can't seem to find out how to update the data in a ASP.Net MVC model on an as needed basis. I have a web grid that displays data from a database table via Entity Framework. The data in the database is updated via other processes and I need to give the user the ability to update the grid with new data when they want to see the latest.

There should be a simple way to do this, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: what happen if you hit F5 on Browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a refresh link like so:

```
@Html.ActionLink("ActionToRefreshModel", "ControllerName")
```

in this actin you get the newer data using EF and

```
return View("ViewThatHasTheGridToBeUpdated", updatedModelOfThatView)
```

I'm assuming that this view is strongly typed, so the grid will have the newer values.

Edit:

I'm new to MVC, but the basics to retrieve data with EF:

```
var myModel = new myModel;
myModel = context.myModels.Find(myModel.Name);
```

This would return the value of the Name property of your myModel model.
Then you return to a View passing this model and the grid autopopulates.

Comment: What I am missing is how you get the new data from the EF.

Comment: @RobertMcCabe Well, How do you show data in the first place? **What is the context's lifespan?** Your question lacks all kinds of relevant information.